# How to merge multiple text files into one new csv file with column header created using Perl

Tags: perl

I am new to Perl and need some guidance. I have multiple text files and want to merge all them into a new csv file. Then, from the csv file, I want to split the string into multiple column as shown in the "Output" format below. Can someone pls help me?

Text File#1.txt

```
Name:A
Test1:80
Test2:60
Test3:50
```

Text File#2.txt

```
Name:B
Test1:85
Test2:78
Test3:60
```

Output (format #1):
New Text File#3.csv

```
Name    Test1   Test2   Test3
A         80    60     50
B         85    78     60
```

Output (format #2):
New Text File#3.csv

```
Name    Test    Data        
A           1   80  
A           2   60
A           3   50
B           1   85
B           2   78
```

Answer (score 1):

reading files:

```
    Open FILE, "filename.txt" or die $!;

    #create hash
    %hash = ();

    #read file - you have to do this for all files
    while (<FILE>) {

    if(first_row){
       $name = (split ':')[1];
    }else{
       $points = split ':'[1];
       push( @{$hash{$name}}, $points );
    }
}
```

at this point you have a hash:

```
A -> [80,60,50]
B -> [85,78,60]
```

you can now use this hash to print your csv file:

for file 1:

```
open CSV1, ">", "1.csv" or die $!

foreach my $name( keys %hash )    
{
  $points = $hash{$name};
  print CSV1 $name + ";" + join(";", @{$points})
  print "/n";
}
```

for file 2:

```
open CSV2, ">", "2.csv" or die $!

foreach my $name( keys %hash )    
{
  $points = $hash{$name};

  $testnumber = 0;
  foreach $point ( in @$points){
      print CSV2 $name + ";" $testnumber+1 + ";" + $point + "\n"; 
  }
}
```

hope this helps you out, if anything is not clear, you can ask.
do not copy paste, it can contain minor errors, but i assume the way of thinking is clear

Update: the ";" is because csv split columns on that character

please feedback